# I am getting error push() is not a function while pushing element in array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, push

> > **I am getting error push() is not a function while pushing element in
> > >array? giving me error lik arry.push is not a function**

```
 var abc=["get","get","get","get","get","get","get","get","get",];
    
     for(i=0;i<abc.length;i++){

    let a=abc[i].push("mate");
 
   console.log(abc);
    }
```

Comment: read more about how `.push` works.

Comment: `abc` is an array, `abc[i]` is an element of the array, in your case a string. `string`s don't have a push method ...

Comment: Can you give me any alternative  to replace all element of array with new one using for loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should delete the [i] in `abc[i].push()` because `abc[i]` is string, but the `.push()` method works for arrays. Therefore you should use `abc.push()` instead of `abc[i].push()`.

Answer (score 1):

When you do abc[i].push(), you're actually calling .push() on the string at index i, not the array. Strings do not have the function .push() which is where your error is coming from

Instead try the following:

```
abc.push("mate");
```

Answer (score 0):

To push elements in an array, simply use the `Array.prototype.push` method.

```
var abc = ["get", "get", "get", "get", "get", "get", "get", "get", "get"]

abc.push("mate")
```

Read more about how push works here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push

The origin point of your error is that, you are accessing each array elements which are strings and trying to use the `push()` method on those.

Answer (score 0):

The **.push() method** is for array only. In the loop, you're using abc[i] which means you're accessing each **element** of the array, **not the whole array.**.

The above method works to add element to end of the array. So use **abc.push()**